# Doctrine repository for entities implementing a common interface

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, orm

I have a few different doctrine entities implementing a common interface and I want to (ideally) create a repository in doctrine that allows me to query with ordering/pagination across all those entities (a union in plain SQL). The entities don't inherit from a common base class.

Specifically the interface allows an object to be used as a tag:

```
interface My\TaggableInterface
{
    // get object UUID
    public function getObjectIdentity(): string
    // get the tag text
    public function getTagString(): string
}

class My\Entity implements My\TaggableInterface

class My\Other\Entity implements My\TaggableInterface
```

I was hoping to create a custom repository that managed the union, so I could write:

```
$entityManager()->getRepository('My\\TaggableInterface')
    ->findBy(
        //criteria
    )`
```

But there doesn't seem to be a way to create a temporary table from an interface or [support for union in the doctrine query builder](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/5657). I want to avoid using native (My)SQL if possible, but I can't see how to achieve this using Doctrine?

Many thanks.

Comment: Cannot share repositories between entities in Doctrine.   You can create a custom repository for each entity then implement your taggable stuff via either a trait or a base repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with a single query. Even if you could somehow construct this query, doctrine wouldn't know how to hydrate the results.

You can however find and query all entities implementing your interface without having to list them all somewhere in your code:

```
$result = array();
$criteria = array(
    // criteria
);
foreach ($em->getMetadataFactory()->getAllMetadata() as $m) {
    $class = $m->getName();
    $reflClass = new \ReflectionClass($class);
    if ($reflClass->implementsInterface('My\TaggableInterface')) {
        $result = array_merge($result, $em->getRepository($class)->findBy($criteria));
    }
}
// results of various entity classes are now all in $result
```

Comment: That's ok, but it means loading all the results of the query to get sorted and paginated data.   I think I'm going to have to use `EntityManager::createNativeQuery` and the `ResultSetMapping` class for what I want, but this is the best that can be done with the ORM.

Comment: Unfortunately, even  with native SQL and ResultSetMapping, AFAIK you can't hydrate different result rows from a UNION query into different entity classes. I think in order to make this work, you would also have to write a custom hydrator (see https://techpunch.co.uk/development/create-custom-doctrine2-hydrator-symfony2 for a start).

Comment: In my case they are all being hydrated to tag entities. I used the MySQL `UUID()` function to create an ID for the new tag, then if the user saves that tag it can be handled exactly the same as the real tag entities from there on (my answer below). It's a little bit messy, but it'll work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

An outline of the solution I used is below. Since I'm hydrating the results from each table into a tag entity (which can be persisted using the ORM if the tag is selected by the user) there's no need to hydrate multiple entity classes from the same result set.

```
$sql = <<<EOF
    SELECT `id`, `text`
    FROM tag_table
    GROUP BY `text`
    UNION
    SELECT UUID() as `id`, `some_text_field` as `text`
    FROM another_table
    GROUP BY `some_text_field`
EOF;

$resultMapping = new ResultSetMapping();
$resultMapping->addEntityResult('My\Tag\Entity', 'tag');
$resultMapping->addFieldResult('tag', 'id', 'id');
$resultMapping->addFieldResult('tag', 'text', 'text');
$nativeQuery = $entityManager->createNativeQuery($sql, $resultMapping);

$result = $nativeQuery->getResult();
```

The SQL can then be extended to handle pagination, and to make sure the tag entity table is used (instead of a newly generated uuid for the same tag text) when duplicate entries across the tables are removed by the union.